# I want to know Complete project line of code in TFS project collection

Tags: tfs

Team,

Could you please help on the advise.

I want to know how to calculate the line of code for my TFS project collection. I need for entire instance to calculate the line of code.

Please advise. Thank you

Comment: Have you resolved the issue by Daniel's answer? I test at my side, it works for me.

Comment: Yes that worked. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'm assuming you're using TFVC, not Git.

You should be able to get this from the [data warehouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/sql-reports/table-reference-relational-warehouse-database) (`Tfs_Warehouse`) assuming you have Reporting Services configured.

There is a [Code Churn table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/sql-reports/table-reference-code-churn). I believe you should be able to sum the `NetLinesAdded` field to get the total number of lines of code.

The [Analysis Cube](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/sql-reports/perspective-code-analyze-report-code-churn-coverage) has a *Total Lines* field, as well.

However, you can also get this information from your file system with PowerShell, for example:

```
(gci -Path 'C:\Users\Daniel\Source\Repos\' -rec -Include '*.cs' | select-string .).Count
```

This comes with the caveat that "lines of code" is, in almost every single case, a totally meaningless, worthless number.